# Issues with NextJs SSR and cookies in Apollo

Tags: next.js, apollo, server-side-rendering

I would like to use cookies for authentication in my nextjs app. I have a bug in my code where the SSR won't work because somewhere in the execution process of the code it does not find the cookie on the first render of the page so it will throw an error. I have played with the code a lot now and have gotten it to a state where the data will eventually load but will not be a SSR page. Has anyone else dealt with this problem? 
I am using next, apollo client and apollo server express.

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

When you do an SSR, the code runs on the server. The cookies you added in browser are not available as default. You can access then in `getInitialProps` or `getServerSideProps` via `req.headers.cookie` and pass it to the authentication code again.

Alternately, you can use an npm module like react-cookie https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie which support isomorphic cookies. More examples on integration are available on the link.

Answer (score 0):

We can custom the headers before sending.

Please check my full answer at this link https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/5089#issuecomment-749301669

```
async function getHeaders(ctx) {
  if (ctx?.req?.cookies) {
    const cookieItems = []
    for (let key of Object.keys(ctx?.req?.cookies)) {
      cookieItems.push(`${key}=${ctx.req.cookies[key]}`)
    }
    return {
      cookie: cookieItems.join('; ')
    }
  }

  return {
  }
}
```

```
WithApollo.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
      const { AppTree } = ctx
      // Initialize ApolloClient, add it to the ctx object so
      // we can use it in `PageComponent.getInitialProp`.
      const apolloClient = (ctx.apolloClient = initApolloClient(null, await getHeaders(ctx)))
      // Run wrapped getInitialProps methods
      let pageProps = {}
      if (PageComponent.getInitialProps) {
        pageProps = await PageComponent.getInitialProps(ctx)
      }

    ............

}
}
```